# Can't delete partition on a USB drive because of different block sizes?

Tags: partitioning

[image]

Have a USB drive that used to be bootable Ubuntu install. I want to repurpose it now but can't delete any of the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

use the command line to format this partition using the following steps (of course by `root user`):

root user):

```
$ fdisk /dev/sdb
```

This will log in to the a disk management in console. type `m` for help (manual). Continue deleting the partitions using `d` and write it to the table using `w`.
All the required information are available [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-delete-a-partition-with-fdisk-command/).